# Maven copying jar to different location while install

Tags: installation, maven-3

I am trying to run an app in an isolated box which does not have access to main maven repo. I was wondering if it is possible for me to create a maven plugin that will identify changed snapshots and copy it over to the isolated box so i can do a build on that isolated box. This needs to be ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a **maven install** on the project on that isolated machine while it is still hooked up it should download all dependencies to that machines local repository.

It should then be possible build on that machine after it is disconnected.

Comment: since the machine is isolated, it will not be able to resolve the dependency when i run "maven install" though? Now i am thinking of a mirror repo on this isolated box but then issue is how to make sure this mirror is set up with correct snapshots.